# Using one method with constants as parameters versus several methods

Tags: language-agnostic

In Kent Beck's [Implementation Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321413091), one can read

> "A common use of constants is to
>   communicate variations of a message in
>   an interface. For example, to center
>   text you could invoke
>   `setJustification(Justification.CENTERED)`.
>   One advantage of this style of API is
>   that you can add new variants of
>   existing methods by adding new
>   constants without breaking
>   implementors. However, these messages
>   don't communicate as well as having a
>   separate method for each variation. In
>   this style, the message above would be
>   `justifyCentered()`. An interface where
>   all invocations of a method have
>   literal constants as arguments can be
>   improved by giving it separate methods
>   for each constant value."

Why is this? Generally when I'm coding and I notice that I have a couple of similar parameterless methods that could be reduced to just one, with an argument, like in the following example,

```
void justifyRight()
void justifyLeft()
void justifyCentered()
```

I'd generally do just the opposite of what Kent advices, which would be to group it into

```
setJustification(Justification justification)
```

How do you usually handle this situation? Is this totally subjective or there is really a very strong reason that I can't see in favour of Kent's view of this matter?

Thanks

Comment: I think its old school programming, when you try to get better performance by code duplication. Later when you need to add another parameter to the method like margin class(with size of left, right, bottom, top margin) you will end up with a lot of code duplication.

Comment: I don't believe it has anything to do with performance (at least, in relationship with this book/author).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File access methods usually have parameters regarding read/write mode, whether to create non-existing files, security attributes, locking modes and so on. Imagine the amount of methods you'd have if you'd create a separate method for each **valid combination of parameters**!

I've highlighted the biggest argument in favor of separate methods; it's fail-safe because you have strict control over the API. The caller cannot pass in invalid arguments, or invalid combinations of parameters, if you don't expose such parameters. This also implies less complex parameter validation.

However, I'm not in favor of this practice. API's should be well-designed and should [change as little as possible](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/04/the-cost-of-breaking-changes.aspx). Kent Beck on breaking API changes:

> One advantage of [parameterized methods] is that you can add new variants of existing methods by adding new constants without breaking implementors.

His argument in favor of separate methods is:

> However, [parameterized methods] don't communicate as well as having a separate method for each variation.

I disagree. Method parameters can be just as readable. Especially in combination with named parameters, a feature which is supported by several languages. Besides, separate methods would result in a cluttered API.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it's subjective. Some may argue that justifyLeft is clearer than justify(Justification.LEFT) Collapsing it all into one method may result in a nicer API - less clutter - and the mode can be stored in a variable and simply feeding it to the single setXY method (with different methods for each, you'd have to decide which to call depending on the value manually). Therefore I usually prefer this way way. Though it's usually just:

```
void justify(Justification justification) {
    switch(justification) {
        Justification.RIGHT: this.justifyRight();
        Justification.LEFT: this.justifyLeft();
        Justification.CENTERED: this.justifyCenter();
    }
}
```

Of course this is only advisable when all these methods *are* very closely related.